# Non-pointer function type can be a non-type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I've been experimenting with function types in C++. Note that I don't mean pointer-to-function types like:

```
typedef void (*voidFuncPtr)();
```

but the more exotic:

```
typedef void (voidFunc)();
```

I didn't expect the following code to compile, but surprisingly it did:

```
template<voidFunc func>
class funcClass
{
public:
    void call() { func(); };
};

void func()
{ }

void Test()
{
    funcClass<func> foobar;
    foobar.call();
}
```

however, if I try adding the following to funcClass:

```
voidFuncPtr get() { return &func; }
```

I get the error `Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator`

My first question here is: what kind of black magic is the compiler using to pretend that a func type is something it can actually pass around an instance of? Is it just treating it like a reference? Second question is: if it can even be called, why can't the address of it be taken? Also, what are these non-pointer-to function types called? I only discovered them because of boost::function, and have never been able to find any documentation about them.

Comment: Which C++ version? C++11 supports lambdas...

Comment: It compiles if you remove the `&` and just `return func;`.

Comment: @hyde This is a theoretical question. I'm using C++11 (XCode 4.5.1), but lambdas don't answer the question - there is no practical application to be solved for.

Comment: @Seth Well what do you know... I guess when you refer to a function name without using () it's the same as taking the address of it, and in the case of being a template parameter that still holds true. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

§14.1.4 of the Standard says:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> — integral or enumeration type,
>
> — pointer to object or **pointer to function**, [*this is what yours is*]
>
> — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
>
> — pointer to member,
>
> — std::nullptr_t.

And §14.1.6 says

> A non-type non-reference template-parameter is a prvalue. It shall not
> be assigned to or in any other way have its value changed. **A non-type
> non-reference template-parameter cannot have its address taken**. When a
> non-type non-reference template-parameter is used as an initializer
> for a reference, a temporary is always used.

So that explains the two behaviours you are seeing.

Note that `func` is the same as `&func` (§14.3.2.1):

> [A non-type template parameter can be] a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a
> function with external or internal linkage, including function
> templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class
> members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, except
> that **the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array**
> and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a
> reference; or...

So it's just a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the code compiles without the address-of operator and pointers (including to functions and member functions) are valid template arguments, it seems the compiler considers `voidFunc` to be a function pointer type, i.e., the decayed version of the type. The rules for this didn't change between C++ 2003 and C++ 2011.